# Do Hazelcast supports synchronous (sync) @Cacheable implementation

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cache, hazelcast-imap

I want to use hazelcast as a cache provider for spring. Let say I am able to configure cluster and pick proper hazelcast CacheManager implementation.

I want to be sure hazelcast cache supports 'sync' annotation attribute as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-synchronized)

I want to be sure writing code like

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="foos", sync=true)
public Foo executeExpensiveOperation(String id) {...}
```

...would guarantee for me that the entry will be locked while cache value will be computed by CacheLoader.

Do modern versions of hazelcast supports synchronous cache implementation?

I know there is distributed read-through IMap with similar behavior as a synchronized cache. And I can explicitly lock map entries by a key. Should I use these structure as an alternative?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is supported as of 3.7 as this [pull request indicates](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/7152/files). It also works if you're using Hazelcast as a JSR107 provider as Spring's JCache abstraction implements this contract as well.

Comment: Does this means now all load operation are synchronized? So now sync=false will not take effect and all is sync=true by default.

Comment: Please look at the javadoc of `@Cacheable`. the default value of `sync` is `false`

Comment: in @Cachable sync = false but hazelcast implementation anyway obtains lock and in fact behaviour is like when sync is true. In pull request you have mention I don't see how behaviour can be switched when sync=true or when sync=false.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: How can I control behavior when before changing map value (or cache value since anyway cache is backed by the map)  hazelcast will obtain lock for that map key or I want to modify map value without obtaining lock for lack of consistency but for performance reasons? Documentation says, as I understand, I can try to control it via sync=true or sync=false. I guess before 3.7 sync by implementation was always false, after 3.7 now it is seems to be always true.